# ByteArrayBody from org.apache.http.entity.mime.content cannot be reached

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having a hard time using the **ByteArrayBody** class from the **org.apache.http.entity.mime.content** in my eclipse project (android app). I copied the **httpmime-4.5.1.jar** in my **libs** folder and did all the stuff in the **javabuild path** (adding the .jar and checking it in Order and Export section).

Looks like this class cannot be reached for some reason, do I miss something including the .jar in my project ? Code looks like this :

```
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

   bp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);

   byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("__mypath__");

   httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data;   boundary="+boundary);

   ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes, "pic.jpg"); //CRASHING HERE

   //...
```

Any help would be appreciated,
thx in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it ! I only included the mime .jar, but I also need the client, the core and the other jars in my libs directory and add them to build path.